# Definite article both feminine and masculine

Tags: articles, gender

If the noun is both feminine and masculine, then what would be the definite article?? For example, for `gente`, it is both feminine and masculine, so what would the definite article be??

Comment: Notice that "gente" is feminine,  so it's "la gente".

Comment: You are probably referring to  the English *IT*. There is no indefinite gender in Italian. All nouns have a gender connotation. A generic one can be feminine like *la cosa* or masculine *il coso* for instance.

Comment: Tia27, would you terribly mind having a look at a dictionary when you have a doubt like this? I promise dictionaries give, for each word, its exact spelling, its gender, its main forms when irregular and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no “generic gender” in Italian: every name is either masculine or feminine. The word *gente* is feminine, so it wants the article *la* even when you're referring to a group of male people.

Another instance is *persona*: if you're talking about a male, you have to use the article *la* (that is, *la persona*) nonetheless.

Words like *gente* or *persona* don't have gender variations like *figlio* and *figlia*, so for them the feminine article will always be used. If a word has gender variation, when talking about “mixed” situations the masculine form is used: *Giacomo ha quattro figli, due maschi e due femmine*.

A few words *can* receive both articles because the masculine and feminine forms share the word; you find some of them at [this article on Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/parole-ambigeneri_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29). Going on with the example above we would say *Giacomo ha salutato i suoi quattro nipoti* even if some of them are male and some female.

Comment: @charo, perché hai tolto 'or both' che avevo aggiunto. Considera 'anatra' per esempio. Essa è sia maschile che femminile.

Comment: Sì, @ElberichSchneider, ma quando stai scrivendo l'articolo devi sempre scegliere tra il maschile o il femminile. Penso che questo sia il senso della frase da egreg. Credo che il tuo "or both" possa causare confusione nel contesto di questa domanda in cui l'OP chiede qual è l'articolo per "a noun that is both feminine and masculine".

Comment: @ElberichSchneider: A proposito del tuo esempio, penso si dica "l'anatra" e non "il anatra" perché il nome è femminile anche se l'uccello può essere maschio.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider Adding “or both” would invalidate my argument: the *anatra* example is not relevant, because it's always feminine. I'm talking about *grammatical gender* that is fixed, although some words *can* have the same form with masculine and feminine grammatical gender. In those cases you choose the relevant one when using the word; so you'll say either *mia nipote Anna* or *mio nipote Luigi*.